# Is it possible to have `i3-msg focus <direction>` to not wrap around when there is no window in the given direction

Tags: i3, window-management

I am using i3 as my window manager, and I would like to avoid wrapping around when pressing `$mod+<direction>`.

For example, If I am in the rightmost window on the workspace, and I press `$mod+right`, I don't want focus to go to the leftmost window, but rather stay in the currently focused window.

[Initially asked in the i3-faq](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/5yyqm9/is_it_possible_to_have_i3msg_focus_direction_to/) and recommended to also post here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I [implemented](https://github.com/i3/i3/pull/2953) this option last year.

Add to your configuration file:

```
focus_wrapping no
```

It is available since version 4.15.